# Facebook PHP SDK - Posting on the wall to all my registered users when they are not active

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I've seen some facebook applications posting status updates on the users wall to all the registered users on the application. How is this possible? I am using PHP SDK and i am able to post to a user when he is logged in on my application but i have no clue on how to do it when they are not on the app and doesnt have an active session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is I save user's Facebook User ID and access_token in a table in the database and then post "whenever needed",  for as long as that user hasn't removed post permissions or the app from Facebook account.

Put this in a loop

```
    $data2 = array();
    $data2['access_token'] = $usersPermission; // from database

    $data2['message'] = 'test message';

    $facebook->api('/'.$facebook_user_id.'/feed/', 'post', $data2);
```

And I can post while the users are not on the app!

Answer (score 1):

You can [exchange your access token for a long-lived one](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/).